Get ETH Balance in etherjs v6
Using web3modal connecting to trust wallet with etherjs
const provider = new ethers.BrowserProvider(walletProvider)
const signer = provider.getSigner()
const balanceWei = await signer.provider.getBalance(userAddress)

Where userAddress is a wallet address of trust wallet and walletProvider is the object getting from useUserWalletConnect
Expecting output : Balance of the wallet
What we getting : 0 balance
